# how to create compressesed SSL/TLS connection on android

Tags: android, compression, zlib, ssl

i want to have an https connection to the server, but in order to conserve bandwidth i want it to be compressed.
I heard that some SSL implementations support compression (i dont mean the zlib encoding of the HTTP payload itself), can it be activated in android?
i couldnt find any reference to it neither in javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
nor in javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory

Comment: i think it's automatically done http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

Comment: @Selvin that blog only describes zip-encoding.

Answer (score -1):

SSL and TLS were defined so as to include a compression feature, but it isn't supported in Java JSSE, i.e. `javax.net.ssl.*`, at least in Oracle's implementation. Use zip-encoding. The zip-encoding happens to the plaintext content, then SSL is applied over that.

**EDIT** Not supported by default in anything else except OpenSSL either as of date. [' conservative implementations do not enable compression at the TLS level'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TLS_implementations)

Comment: Not really. Compression is supported in TLS since 2004. Check http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3749